# NoSQL aggregation query Shakespeare’s dataset

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to learn NoSQL aggregation queries and here is dataset (name - shakespeare_plays) structure:

```
    "_id" : "Romeo and Juliet",
    "acts" : [ 
        {
            "title" : "ACT I",
            "scenes" : [ 
                {
                    "title" : "SCENE I. Verona. A public place.",
                    "action" : [ 
                        {
                            "character" : "SAMPSON",
                            "says" : [ 
                                "Gregory, o' my word, we'll not carry coals."
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "character" : "GREGORY",
                            "says" : [ 
                                "No, for then we should be colliers."
]
                        }, 
                        // ...
                        {
                            "character" : "GREGORY",
                            "says" : [ 
                                "To move is to stir; and to be valiant is to stand:", 
                                "therefore, if thou art moved, thou runn'st away."
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "character" : "SAMPSON",
                            "says" : [ 
                                "A dog of that house shall move me to stand: I will", 
                                "take the wall of any man or maid of Montague's."
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "character" : "GREGORY",
                            "says" : [ 
                                "That shows thee a weak slave; for the weakest goes", 
"to the wall."
                            ]
                        }, 
                        // ...
                },
                // ...
            ]
        },
        // ...
    ]
}
```

What tasks am I trying to do:

- What characters are found in more than one play
- How many replicas does Juliet have
- Number of characters in Othello

Any tips how to do it via aggregate?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?`

Comment: I tried to use $unwind for all tags, so I could probably count 1st or 3rd task, but, well, after my unwind I have no idea how to continue...                                               ```db.getCollection('shakespeare_plays').aggregate([{$unwind: "$acts"},{$unwind: "$acts.scenes"},{$unwind: "$acts.scenes.action"},{$unwind: "$acts.scenes.action.says"}``` I only know that after $unwind I should use $group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. Sharing some queries to achieve your goal.

From where you're right now, you can get a list of all characters by adding `$group` stage

```
db.getCollection('shakespeare_plays').aggregate([{
  $unwind: "$acts"
}, {
  $unwind: "$acts.scenes"
}, {
  $unwind: "$acts.scenes.action"
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: "$acts.scenes.action.character"
  }
}])
```

Going further, you want to see who has appeared how many times, you can use `$sum` operator inside `$group`

```
db.getCollection('shakespeare_plays').aggregate([{
  $unwind: "$acts"
}, {
  $unwind: "$acts.scenes"
}, {
  $unwind: "$acts.scenes.action"
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: "$acts.scenes.action.character",
    count: {$sum: 1}
  }
}])

//Results : [{ "_id" : "GREGORY", "count" : 4 }]
```

You can export the results to an array and perform any logic you want to perform on the results which will give you all the answers you needed

```
var myResults = db.getCollection('shakespeare_plays').aggregate([pipelineQuery]).toArray();

//Here you can perform any logic on the variable myResults in your programming language
```

Read more about [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) and [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)

Comment: @Cynic_4769 It's good to see as a new contributor, you have shared a lot of details with the question which made it easy for me to test the results and share it with you. Do upvote the answer and accept the answer(tick mark) if this helped you.